# Flickering issue in BBLWUIT virtualkeyboard

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-vkb

I have problem with virtual keyboard as whenever it pops up it flickers and displays a white screen and pops up. Does anyone have faced such problem?

It happens in BBLwuit version 1.4. I am using the native BB virtual keyboard I have checked. Mainly for the device BB Torch 9800 version 6.0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide information about your version of LWUIT and the specific application. Check whether this happens for LWUIT demo applications such as the LWUIT demo and make sure that you are using the native virtual keyboard.

Its possible you are getting flickering since you have too many elements in the screen and repainting them takes too long.

Comment: It happens in BBLwuit version 1.4 .I am using the native BB virtual keyboard I have checked .Mainly for the device BB Torch 9800 version 6.0

Comment: I suggest you check this on a current version of LWUIT. 1.4 isn't even supported on the torch.